# Camel: how to skip folders during initial upload?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have the Camel route which looks like:

```
 from("sftp://....."+ 
            "&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true" +
            "&consumer.delay=10000" +
            "&recursive=true" +
            "&antInclude=*/*.xml" +
            "&idempotent=true" + 
            "&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron="+ env.getProperty("camel.scheduler.cron")+""+ 
            "&filterDirectory=${date:now:yyyyMMdd}").
```

When I start application, Camel get all folders from FTP, but I need only `20170221` (current date in `yyyyMMdd` format).

So the question is: how to upload only current date folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `filterDirectory`, try using `antInclude`, like so: `"antInclude=${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/*.xml"`